# compare intersection of certain columns of dataframes sized different

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have some troubles to compare two dataframes in the way I'd like:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"code1": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C','D'],
               "code2": ["1", "0", "1", "1","1"],
               "column1":['value1','value2','value3','value4','value5']})

    code1 code2 column1
  0     A     1  value1
  1     B     0  value2
  2     C     1  value3
  3     C     1  value4
  4     D     1  value5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"code1": ['A','B','C'],
               "code2": ["0", "0", "1"],
               "column2":['valuex','valuey','valuez']})

     code1 code2 column2
   0     A     0  valuex
   1     B     0  valuey
   2     C     1  valuez
```

These are the two dataframe I'd like to compare. I need to do something like

```
 df1[['code1','code2']].isin(df2[['code1','code2']])
```

with the purpose of getting the result:

```
     code1 code2 column1
   0     B     0  value2
   1     C     1  value3
   2     C     1  value4
```

I want to preserve the rows having same 'code1' and 'code2' in both df1 and df2, and the other columns of df1.
Do you know the best way to do this?? I would like to avoid loops, I need it to be eficient.
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method:

```
In [30]: cols = ['code1','code2']

In [31]: pd.merge(df1, df2[cols], on=cols)
Out[31]:
  code1 code2 column1
0     B     0  value2
1     C     1  value3
2     C     1  value4
```

**UPDATE:**

> what if I want to retain the deleted cases in another dataframe?

```
In [62]: pd.merge(df1, df2[cols], on=cols, how='left', indicator=True).query("_merge == 'left_only'")
Out[62]:
  code1 code2 column1     _merge
0     A     1  value1  left_only
4     D     1  value5  left_only
```

Comment: ok thank you! And what if I want to retain the deleted cases in another dataframe???

Comment: @emilio.molina, please see UPDATE

Comment: perfect, thank you very much!! so 'indicator' is the parameter which decides    which part of the dataframe you conserve, isn't it?

Comment: Another problem related: What if the name of the df2 columns are different? For example CODE1, CODE2. And this is my last question about this! thank you again!

Comment: @emilio.molina, use `left_on` and `right_on` parameters instead of `on`

Comment: yeah! thank you very much!! I didn't know all capacities of merge()

Answer (score 0):

I would set the index to the columns you want and perform a join:

```
df1=df1.set_index(['code1','code2'])    
df2=df2.set_index(['code1','code2'])
In [90]: df1.join(df2)
Out[90]: 
            column1 column2
code1 code2                
A     1      value1     NaN
B     0      value2  valuey
C     1      value3  valuez
      1      value4  valuez
D     1      value5     NaN
```

To get rid of the NaN: `dropna`

```
df1.join(df2)
Out[94]: 
            column1 column2
code1 code2                
B     0      value2  valuey
C     1      value3  valuez
      1      value4  valuez
```

and then you could discard the index if you don't want it with `reset_index()`:

```
df1.join(df2).dropna().reset_index()
Out[95]: 
  code1 code2 column1 column2
0     B     0  value2  valuey
1     C     1  value3  valuez
2     C     1  value4  valuez
```

Comment: that's fine. Thank you very much. However I have two problems. First is that I have made the question in that sense, but actually I wanted to retain the others values, i.e. the values with NaN in column 2. My second problem is that df2 has many columns (63). So doing it that way makes me to delete all the added columns, something quite awful....

Comment: by the way, I'm sorry but I cannot add points until I get 15 of reputation, so I cannot accept your answer... I'm sure anyone else will do it, don't worry

Comment: ok I did it. however, althought your answer has been useful, it doesn't solve completely my problem and I would like to get other answers... I don't know if others will care about this question if it's been marked as solved...